# Android Studio shows old logs

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio **v1.3.1** and when I am running a project on real device, I have to **wait couple minutes till actual logs comes up** in log console using *Verbose* & *Show only selected application*. If I choose *No filtres* it shows me older logs coming up, like 2-5 mins again. After all old logs are showed in console, it comes the news ones... I tried to restart logs, but it begins again to show old and then actual.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can reset your log from command like like this: `adb logcat -c` that will clear old log messages. You could try LogRabbit which has a lot of other features as well. Or in Android Studio you can reset logs when starting app in logcat configurations.

Answer (score 1):

This issue(port issue) sometime happens if logcat does not clear the recent output caches on plugged devices.

*AndroidStudio Solution (Clear all outputs and device ports)*

1. **Plug-Out your devices or close any emulators**
2. **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart > Press "Just Restart"**

Also it's recommended to run any project with fully cleared logcat.

3. **Run > Edit Configurations > Tab(Logcat) > CheckBox(Clear log before launch)**

I personally would always log through terminal.

*Terminal Solution*

Just check if your device is plugged

```
path/to/android_sdk/platform-tools/./adb devices
```

Log your devices

```
path/to/android_sdk/platform-tools/./adb logcat
```

To get all logcat terminal options, see link below:

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

The entire log file is stored into the device storage, it can be extracted to the system so you can see the previous logs from the file.

Connect your device and run the command in terminal.

```
adb logcat -d > logcat.txt
```